# How do I merge array items when they have corresponding array values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript array that has subarrays, these subarrays have two values, a year and a number

```
var abc = [["2012", "399"], 
           ["2012", "114"], 
           ["2012", "151"], 
           ["2013", "116"], 
           ["2013", "145"], 
           ["2013", "280"], 
           ["2013", "84"], 
           ["2014", "5"], 
           ["2014", "228"], 
           ["2014", "156"], 
           ["2014", "43"], 
           ["2014", "27"]];
```

I want to have the total sum of the second value for each year. So for my example array I would want the following output:

```
Year: 2012 Sum: 664

Year: 2013 Sum: 625

Year: 2014 Sum: 459
```

I'm pretty much stuck at checking for the first value and adding these in to an array.

**[FIND FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud55g/2/)**

Any suggestions on comparing the first value in my array?

Comment: you want for specific for these 3 years or generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an array of objects like you want

```
var result = [];
$.each( abc, function( key, value ) {
    var matched = false;
    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
        if(value[0]==result[i].year){
            result[i].sum += (+value[1]);
            matched=true;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if(!matched)
        result.push({year:value[0],sum:(+value[1])});
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    var val = parseInt(abc[i][1], 10);
    var year = abc[i][0];
    if (year in result) {
        result[year] += val;
    } else {
        result[year] = val;
    }
}
for (year in result) {
    console.log('Year: ' + year + ' Sum: ' + result[year]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array, use the first array element as the key to a `result` object, and add accordingly

```
var results = {};
abc.forEach(function(data){
   results[data[0]] = results[data[0]] || 0;
   results[data[0]] += +data[1];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare the first value, use it as a key in the sum array, that will be much easier...

```
var abc = [["2012", "399"], ["2012", "114"], ["2012", "151"], ["2013", "116"], ["2013", "145"], ["2013", "280"], ["2013", "84"], ["2014", "5"], ["2014", "228"], ["2014", "156"], ["2014", "43"], ["2014", "27"]];

var sum = new Array();

$.each( abc, function( key, value ) {
    //Check if value is the same as others in array?
    if (typeof sum[value[0]] === "undefined") {
        sum[value[0]] = parseInt(value[1]);
    } else {
        sum[value[0]] += parseInt(value[1]);
    }
});

$.each(sum, function(key, val) {
    console.log("Year = " + key + " Sum = " + val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could add it to an object with the year as a key and sum it there.

```
var years = {'2012': 0, '2013': 0, '2014': 0};
abc.forEach(function (value) {
   years[value[0]] += parseInt(value[1], 10);
});
Object.keys(years).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log('Year:', key, 'Sum:', years[key]);
});
```